# Android Things with Raspberry Pi for Bmx280SensorDriver Example is not working

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Example Link:
https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/blob/master/bmx280/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/driversamples/TemperatureActivity.java

It shows a exception:

> `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`
>   `ComponentInfo{com.kmk.test/com.kmk.test.MainActivity}:`
>   `java.lang.SecurityException: Caller lacks required permission`
>   `com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_SENSOR_DRIVERS`

But I have added the permission in manifests.

Please Help me...

Comment: "Note: If you are not using Android Studio 3.0 or later, you need to reboot your device after installing the app in order to gain the permission" https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/sensors.html

Comment: If that's not it (more than likely) then you may just need to ask for permission at runtime. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Android Things doesn't support permission requests at runtime. All permissions are granted, although it may take a reboot.

Answer (score 4):

You usually need to reboot your device for the permissions to be granted.

See the following note: [Android things overview](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#permissions)

Answer (score 0):

com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.5.1-devpreview must work on Android Things 0.5. Can not work on 0.4 or lower version.